# URL with Rewrite in Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want the URLs to look clean and nice with rewrite. I was able to do this while using Apache, but I installed Nginx on the server. So I don't use `.htaccess`.

While using Apache, I was using it like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteBase / 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt)$ 
    RewriteRule ^ - [L] 
     RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2 [L,QSA] 
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?cmd=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Example this URL looked like this:

```
https://example.com/item/1234/bund123
```

Without mod_rewrite:

```
https://example.com/index.php?item?id=1234&unt=bund123
```

I tried to do this Nginx but got 404 error. What could be the reason for this?

```
server {

    listen *:80;
        listen [::]:80;
        listen *:443 ssl http2;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        root   /var/www/example.com/web/;

        rewrite ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2 last;
        rewrite ^([^/]+)?$ /index.php?cmd=$1 last;
 
    ....
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details about the 404 error can be found in the Nginx error log.  Presumably, index.php does not exist.

Rewrite rules can be quickly tested with `redirect` and Curl:

```
# /item/cmd/scd
rewrite ^/item/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2 redirect;

# /item/cmd
rewrite ^/item/([^/]+)         /index.php?cmd=$1        redirect;
```

```
$ curl -I https://example.com/item/CMD/SCD
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://example.com/index.php?cmd=CMD&scd=SCD

$ curl -I https://example.com/item/CMD
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://example.com/index.php?cmd=CMD
```

When the rewrites are working properly, change `redirect` to `break`:

```
rewrite ^/item/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2 break;
rewrite ^/item/([^/]+)         /index.php?cmd=$1        break;
```

Comment: There are many pages on the website. One of them is `item`. I am displaying details of objects with the `item` page. I tried your method but got a 404 error with this: `https://example.com/item/objectID` - with this I get a 403 error: `https://example.com/index.php?cmd=item&scd=objectID`  Did I do something wrong? -- [All Conf. Content](https://pastebin.com/gc9gPHZd)

Comment: If it starts with  `rewrite ^/item/(..` does it not affect other pages? For example, category display page, contact… `CMD` is a page name

Comment: `CMD`: Page - `SCD`: option argument (category ID, item ID..)

Comment: Sorry, 404 is stuck in a different tab. I mixed it up, my fault. I just get a 403 error. All code inside the config file belongs to ISPconfig. I just added your code below the page.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I noticed that you are experiencing the 403 Error due to the difference in PHP version and I fixed it.